# Cannot read property 'notificationHub' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working to get notification in my MVC app using SignalR but I am getting below error  **Cannot read property 'notificationHub' of undefined** while debugging on browser at last line of code

```
 public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        //public void Hello()
        //{
        //    Clients.All.hello();
        //}
    }



private void SqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
                var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
                notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
                RegisterNotification(DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" ></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
```

Comment: Please show your Hub class.

Comment: Added Hub class in question after editing it

Answer (score 0):

Mapping hubs to the SignalR pipeline in this way:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;  
using Owin;  
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WeatherAppDemo.SignalR.StartUp))]  
namespace WeatherAppDemo.SignalR {  
    public class StartUp {  
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {  
            app.MapSignalR();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

we have to  do two things- 
 1. we are first starting the StartUp class
 2. adding the hubs to the SignalR pipeline

Now you have to check this url:

```
http://localhost:58416/signalr/hubs
```

//http://localhost:58416 this will be your own localhost

If you are able to see the JavaScript code, then you have successfully configured a SignalR Server.
Then I hope you have found no error

Answer (score 0):

I am resolving this issue by delete "NotificationHub.cs" and then add new "SignalR Hub Class(v2)" in my project and give "NotificationHub" name of this class.